# (Evasi0n JB) iOS 6 launchd change in syntax?

Tags: ios, launchd

Is there any change in the syntax of the launchd (LaunchDaemons) files from iOS 5.x to iOS 6.1?

I tried to install somethingfrom my iOS 5.1 iPhone4s to the iPhone5 (running iOS 6.1 JB with Evasi0n) and it gives me this error (in /var/log/syslog):

```
com.apple.launchd[1] (com.mydom.myScrpt[2601]): (com.mydom.myScrpt) Exited with code: 1
```

And it's not a "myScrpt" problem, because I change myScrpt to:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "----Test---"
```

but the only thing in /var/log/syslog was the error and nothing else
(doing the same in my iPhone4s, prints the `"----Test---"` line).

The syntax of my launchd file (that runs myScrpt at 14:00 as root) is

```
{
    Label = "com.mydom.myScrpt";
    LowPriorityIO = 1;
    Nice = 9;
    ProgramArguments =     (
        "/private/var/root/bin/myScrpt"
    );
    StartCalendarInterval =     {
        Hour = 14;
        Minute = 00;
    };
    UserName = root;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How should I write my launchd file to run my command at 14:00?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add on your launchd file this:

```
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/var/log/syslog.mine</string>
```

to get the output of your script.

This is probably the "change" from iOS5 to iOS6.
Now you have to specify the output, 'syslog' is not used by default.